# Cannot run bdist_wheel build command on my setup.py

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-wheel

I have created a pypi package for educational purposes, and I wanted to do an upgrade. I did through the usual steps(do the changes, run setup.py etc)

but when I do:

```
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

I am getting the error

```
 python3 setup.py build bdist_wheel
 usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
 or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
 or: setup.py --help-commands
 or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
```

Wheel and pip are installed and up to date:

```
pip3 install wheel
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist- 
packages (0.31.0)
```

The help of the command, does not seem to support bdist_wheel.

Am I missing something?

```
    python3 setup.py --help-commands
Standard commands:
build             build everything needed to install
build_py          "build" pure Python modules (copy to build directory)
build_ext         build C/C++ extensions (compile/link to build directory)
build_clib        build C/C++ libraries used by Python extensions
build_scripts     "build" scripts (copy and fixup #! line)
clean             clean up temporary files from 'build' command
install           install everything from build directory
install_lib       install all Python modules (extensions and pure Python)
install_headers   install C/C++ header files
install_scripts   install scripts (Python or otherwise)
install_data      install data files
sdist             create a source distribution (tarball, zip file, etc.)
register          register the distribution with the Python package index
bdist             create a built (binary) distribution
bdist_dumb        create a "dumb" built distribution
bdist_rpm         create an RPM distribution
bdist_wininst     create an executable installer for MS Windows
check             perform some checks on the package
upload            upload binary package to PyPI

Extra commands:
alias             define a shortcut to invoke one or more commands
bdist_egg         create an "egg" distribution
develop           install package in 'development mode'
easy_install      Find/get/install Python packages
egg_info          create a distribution's .egg-info directory
install_egg_info  Install an .egg-info directory for the package
rotate            delete older distributions, keeping N newest files
saveopts          save supplied options to setup.cfg or other config file
setopt            set an option in setup.cfg or another config file
test              run unit tests after in-place build
upload_docs       Upload documentation to PyPI

usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
or: setup.py --help-commands
or: setup.py cmd --help
```

EDIT:

```
 python3 --version
 Python 3.6.3


 pip3 --version
 pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip (python 3.4)
```

Comment: Your `pip3` seems to be from a different `python3`. Show us `python3 --version` and `pip3 --version`.

Comment: You are so right, I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like pip version and python version didnt match...fixing this removed the problem.